# Multiple columns in table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I have this table below and I have been ever since trying to make the column work, but it just does not appear like this at all. [image]

The first and the second column are fine, but when it comes to the fact that the 3rd and the 4th column splits into 4 sub columns gives a hard time.

Comment: I noticed that you've set the tag "tabularx". Are you looking to use that particular environment, instead of (say) a "tabular" environment?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It was suppose to be tabular. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to contemplate displaying your table in landscape mode, especially if you want to avoid having to resort to minuscule font sizes. In the code below, I use `\allowbreak` directives to introduce line breaks in some of the columns. I would also like to recommend (i) not using any vertical lines in the table and (ii) using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  % specify page size
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % specify text block size
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,amssymb,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\swb{{\scriptstyle\Box}} % "small white box"
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{10}{C}@{}} 
\toprule
 $\delta_m$ & $2 \neq \swb$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$5 \cdot 29 \neq \swb$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$13 \cdot 1789 \neq \swb$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-10}
    &   & $5=\swb$ & $29\neq\swb$ & $5\neq\swb$ & $29=\swb$ & $13=\swb$ & $1789\neq\swb$ & $13\neq\swb$ & $1789=\swb$ \\
\midrule
Primes that satisfy the condition $\delta_m \neq \swb$  & 
$q\equiv\pm3\pmod8$ & 
$q\equiv\pm1\pmod5$ & 
$q\equiv 2,3,8,10,\allowbreak11,12,14,15,\allowbreak17,18,19,21,\allowbreak26,27\pmod{29}$ & 
$q\equiv\pm2\pmod5$ & 
$q\equiv 1,4,5,6,\allowbreak7,9,13,16,20,\allowbreak22,23,24,25,\allowbreak28\pmod{29}$ & 
$q\equiv 1,3,4,9,\allowbreak10,12\pmod{13}$ & 
$q\equiv A\pmod{1789}$ & 
$q\equiv2,5,6,7,\allowbreak8,11\pmod{13}$ & 
$q\equiv B\pmod{1789}$ \\ 
\midrule
 Period of $w_n$  & $24$ & $30$ & $102$ & $30$ & $102$ & $30$ & $2670$ & $30$ & $2670$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the reverse actually: you should not split one column in to four columns, Use four columns and merge them in to one.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{l|}} \hline
  1 & 2 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{3 to 6} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{7 to 10} \\\cline{3-10}
    &   & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `tabularx` as stated in comments below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{10}{X|}} \hline
  1 & 2 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{3 to 6} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{7 to 10} \\\cline{3-10}
    &   & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Harish this is exactly what I needed. Thank you for explaining the reverse part as well.

Comment: i was wondering how if I want all the 10 columns to have same width? probably like 1.7cm width for each column. because at the moment some columns are wider than the other.

Comment: @Sharina Use `p{1.7cm}` instead of `c` column types. If you want the table to span `\texwidth`, use `\usepackage{tabularx}` and then `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{10}{X|}`

Comment: This is what I did  :                                                                 \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{10}{X|} \hline
  1 & 2 & \multicolumn{4}{ p{1.7cm} |}{3 to 6} & \multicolumn{4}{ p{1.7cm} |}{7 to 10} \\\cline{3-10}
    &   & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}      But it gave runaway argument.

Comment: @Sharina Please see the edit.

Comment: I used the code given and this is what I get. The table columns are too small. Is there any way I could make the table fit the whole page. I posted the image of the output below.